# Laravel 8.6 login using url parameters through middleware

Tags: laravel, authentication, url, middleware

My page in the application is embeded in another application. To get to the embeded page username and password are passed using the URL like `&user=foo&password=bar`. The route to this page goes through a `middleware('loginViaApp')`. I want this middleware to login using the parameters, but i don't know how to login this way. I would expect something like this, but i don't know how to login using middleware.

class LoginViaApp:

```
    {
        if(Auth::login(['username'=>'foo','password'=>'bar'])){
          return $next($request);
        }else{
          return error('403');
        }

    }
```

Can somebody please help me figure out how to login using middleware with parameters in the url?

Kind regards,
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this logic for that, just modify it according to your need and use it in middleware

```
$user = User::where('username',$username)->first();
if(null === $user ){
    return redirect()->route('login');
}
$passwordPass = Hash::check($password, $user->password);
if($passwordPass){
    auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);
    return $next($request);
}
return;
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! This saved me a lot of time. Thank you very much!